# Joomla 3.4.8 webite not loading after trying to update Smart Slider

Tags: joomla-3.x, server

We are running Joomla 3.4.8 on Windows Server 2012. After an update to update Smart Slider was tried, the whole site went blank.

1. How to restore a Joomla site if an extension update like Smart Slider fails?
2. What permissions does Joomla 3.4.8 need to run on Windows server 2012?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "whole site went blank" are you referring to the front-end only or the back-end as well?

Comment: Both front-end and back-end went blank.

Answer (score 2):

A blank screen in Joomla mostly signifies a php error. Check in your configuration.php file the level of error reporting and set to maximum  or development.

You should then be able to see any errors that are occurring after the update.

Comment: Thanks Somy, The site is back-up but I still need to update Smart Slider.